# Need more control over Pentaho PI chart slices

Tags: charts, pentaho, pie-chart

Pentaho gives you the option of easily generating a PI chart using it's report designer. I have a query that can return the following values

```
Over Inflated
Under Inflated
Within Specification
```

These values will each represent a slice within the PI chart. I have two problems.

---

**Problem number 1**

---

I have a query returning the following,

```
Over Inflated
Within Specification
Within Specification
Over Inflated
Over Inflated
Over Inflated
```

Note that the results do not include a single value that is equal to ***Under Inflated***. This will result in a pie chart as indicated below.

[image]

I need the pie chart to indicate to the user that there is also a third slice represented within this chart (Under Inflated). Even though the value for ***Under Inflated*** records is 0%.

---

**Problem number 2**

---

Pentaho gives you the option to specify the colors of the slices. I need to link the colors of the slices to a specific value. For instance ***Over Inflated*** should be displayed as red, ***Under Inflated*** should be displayed as orange and ***Within Specification*** should be displayed as green.

Is there any way in Pentaho to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to bind colours in PRD other than by ensuring the data is in a consistent sort, and defining the colours in that order - i.e. it wont always work.

However saying that you can bind the actual data values if you use a beanshell chart processing script.

To get the 0% slice appear you just ensure your data set returns it.  So the best way to do this is just to outer join from your dimensions to the actual data, then you'll always get the 3 values - even if one is zero.

If you want more/ultimate control you could move to ccc charts. PRD is moving to ccc charts in the future anyway - but unfortunately the only way to use these currently would be to link via CGG - not a perfect scenario (not least of all because that needs a running server too).  But a possibility.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case. Thank you for taking the time to answer this. I will take the time to play around and see if I can work around this as you suggested above.

Comment: I will have to look at a different tool. This is just not giving me enough control.